# Automatic discount for paying customers in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, coupon

I want to apply a discount coupon automatically to everyone who has made at least one purchase on my website. This is the code that I tried but I get a fatal error on the page ...

```
function has_bought( $customer_email ){
    $orders = get_posts(array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'shop_order',
        'post_status' => array('wc-completed'),
    )  );

    $email_array = array();

    foreach($orders as $order) {
        $order_obj = wc_get_order($order->ID);
        $order_obj_data = $order_obj->get_data();

        array_push($email_array, $order_obj_data['billing']['email']);
    }


    if (in_array($customer_email, $email_array)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'apply_matched_coupons' );
function apply_matched_coupons() {
    global $woocommerce;

    $coupon_code = '10fidelity'; // coupon code

    if ( $woocommerce->cart->has_discount( $coupon_code ) ) return;

    if ( has bought() {
        $woocommerce->cart->add_discount( $coupon_code );
        $woocommerce->show_messages();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your actual code is heavy and outdated… Instead try the following much more lighter and efficient way, that use the `WC_Customer` `is_paying_customer` property:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'enable_customer_fidelity_discount', 10, 1 );
function enable_customer_fidelity_discount( $cart ) {
    if ( ! ( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) )
        return;

    if ( ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) || ! is_user_logged_in() )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // The discount coupon code below
    $coupon_code = '10fidelity';

    if( ! in_array( $coupon_code, $cart->get_applied_coupons() ) && WC()->customer->get_is_paying_customer() ) {
        $cart->apply_coupon( $coupon_code );
    } elseif( in_array( $coupon_code, $cart->get_applied_coupons() ) && ! WC()->customer->get_is_paying_customer() ) {
        $cart->remove_coupon( $coupon_code );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works

---

Or using this improved and light function that checks if customer has already made an order:

```
function has_bought( $user_id = 0 ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $customer_id = $user_id == 0 ? get_current_user_id() : $user_id;
    $paid_order_statuses = array_map( 'esc_sql', wc_get_is_paid_statuses() );

    $results = $wpdb->get_col( "
        SELECT p.ID FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        WHERE p.post_status IN ( 'wc-" . implode( "','wc-", $paid_order_statuses ) . "' )
        AND p.post_type LIKE 'shop_order'
        AND pm.meta_key = '_customer_user'
        AND pm.meta_value = $customer_id
    " );

    // Count number of orders and return a boolean value depending if higher than 0
    return count( $results ) > 0 ? true : false;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'enable_customer_fidelity_discount', 10, 1 );
function enable_customer_fidelity_discount( $cart ) {
    if ( ! ( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) )
        return;

    if ( ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) || ! is_user_logged_in() )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // The discount coupon code below
    $coupon_code = 'summer';

    if( ! in_array( $coupon_code, $cart->get_applied_coupons() ) && has_bought() ) {
        $cart->apply_coupon( $coupon_code );
    } elseif( in_array( $coupon_code, $cart->get_applied_coupons() ) && ! has_bought() ) {
        $cart->remove_coupon( $coupon_code );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

Related:

- [Checking if customer has already bought something in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874189/checking-if-customer-has-already-bought-something-in-woocommerce/46216073#46216073)
- [Auto apply coupon only one time per user based on total spent in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55821613/auto-apply-coupon-only-one-time-per-user-based-on-total-spent-in-woocommerce/55822058#55822058)

Comment: I have also tried the code that you put in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55821613/auto-apply-coupon-only-one-time-per-user-based-on-total-spent-in-woocommerce/ 55822058 # 55822058 and I get syntax error from this line // If the coupon has already been used by the customer, we exit

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @LoicTheAztec! I have tried both codes and none of them works, the coupon does not apply. I discovered that if I delete this line from your code it works (although I get many coupon messages added and try to end the purchase automatically) "if (! (Is_cart () || is_checkout ())) return; "